# Export module via Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am working on a React app. In `index.js` am exporting some variables, e.g.

```
export const a="Hello";
export const b=[1,2,3];
```

In webpack.config.js:

```
...
output: {
 ...
 library: "myApp",
 libraryTarget: "window"
},
...
```

I know `window.myApp` is now a `module` which includes all the exported variables from `index.js`. What I do not know is how the above works. How this module is being created and why it includes only the exports from index.js and not other files as well? How, may I include exports from another specific file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your module is being created based on the entry configuration and the other modules and plugins that you configure and is converted to a build file based on the configuration provided in the `output` config of webpack.

`library` setup is tied to the entry configuration so if you specify the entry to be `index.js`, your exports from within the `index.js` are available within the build

In order to also expose exports from other files, you can import and export them from the index file like

```js
    export { default as SomeFunction} from 'some-function.js';
```

According to the [`webpack docs`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library):

> For
>   most libraries, specifying a single entry point is sufficient. While
>   multi-part libraries are possible, it is simpler to expose partial
>   exports through an index script that serves as a single entry point.
>   Using an array as an entry point for a library is not recommended.

`libraryTarget` specifies how the module is exposed. For instance in your case your module is exposed on the `window` object.

> You can expose the library in the following ways:
>
> - **Variable**: as a global variable made available by a script tag (libraryTarget:'var').
> - **This**: available through the this object (libraryTarget:'this').
> - **Window**: available through the window object, in the browser (libraryTarget:'window').
> - **UMD**: available after AMD or CommonJS require (libraryTarget:'umd').
>
> If library is set and libraryTarget is not, libraryTarget defaults to
>   var as specified in the output configuration documentation. See
>   output.libraryTarget there for a detailed list of all available
>   options.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solution to include other files

First is to use multiple entries in your webpack module

```
module.exports = {
    // mode: "development || "production",
    entry: {
        A: "./CompA",
        B: "./CompB"
    },
```

Second approach is use one  entry like your solution, but need to add wrappere.js

wrapper.js

```
import * as a from './CompA.js'
import * as b from './CompB.js'

export a,b
```

And your wrapper become the single entry, where you can access later wrapper.a,wrapper.b

```
module.exports = {
        // mode: "development || "production",
        entry: {
            app: "./wrapper.js",

        },
```